# Correct permissions for a services callback?

Tags: 7, services

I wrote a service that, when called and passed the parameters correctly, creates a node of a certain content type. My service endpoint requires authentication, but so far only the maintenance (user 1) of the site can consume this service correctly, any other user gets an "access denied for user xxx", even if this other users have permissions to create that content type.

The content type is managed by [Room Reservations](https://www.drupal.org/project/room_reservations), and I have created that content type with the other users through the webpage.

The service definition:

```
function room_reservations_services_resources(){
$room_service = array(
'room_reservations'=>array(
  'operations' => array(
    'create' => array(
      'help' => 'Book a reservation',
      'file' => array(
        'type' => 'inc',
        'module'=> 'room_reservations',
        'name' => 'includes/room_reservations.service'
        ),
      'callback' => '_room_reservations_book_reservation_service',
          //'access_callback' => 'user access',
      'access_arguments' => array('create room reservations standard','bypass minimum advance booking'),
      'access_arguments_append' => TRUE,
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'node',
          'type' => 'array',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => 'data',
          'description' => 'All the node information to book a reservation',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'actions'=>array(
      'get_times'=>array(
        'help'=>'Gets the hours and the days reservations can be made',
        'file'=>array(
          'type'=>'inc',
          'module'=>'room_reservations',
          'name'=>'room_reservations'
          ),
        'callback'=>'_room_reservations_service_get_open_hours',
        'access arguments'=>array('view room reservations calendar'),
        'access arguments append'=>FALSE,
        ),
      'get_reservations'=>array(
        'help'=>'Get the reservations from the current loged-in user',
        'file'=>array(
          'type'=>'inc',
          'module'=>'room_reservations',
          'name'=>'room_reservations'
          ),
        'callback'=>'_room_reservations_user_reservations',
        ),
      ),
    ),
);

watchdog("room_reservations","Ran hook_services_resources",null,WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
return $room_service;
```

get_hours works without problems, while the create operation only works with the maintenance user of the site.

Callback function:

```
function _room_reservations_book_reservation_service($args){
//crear el nodo, junto con todas las salvedades
global $user;
$response = "";
if (isset($args)) {
// Create the node
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'room_reservations_reservation';
$node->title = $args['nombre'];
//$node->title = 'Prueba random 1';
$node->language = 'es';
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node->status = 1;
$node->comment = 0;
//node_object_prepare($node);

$node->reservation_date['und'][0] = array(
    'value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($args['fecha'])),
    'timezone' => 'America/Bogota',
    'timezone' => 'America/Bogota',
  );

$node->reservation_length['und'][0]['value'] = '60';
$node->reservation_repeat_type['und'][0]['value'] = '1';
$node->reservation_repeat_until['und'][0] = array(
    'value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($args['fecha'])),
    'timezone' => 'America/Bogota',
    'timezone' => 'America/Bogota',
  );
$node->reservation_room['und'][0]['target_id'] = $args['sala'];
$node->reservation_time['und'][0]['value'] = $args['hora'];
$node->field_codigo_reservation['und'][0]['value'] = $args['codigo'];
$node->field_email_registro['und'][0]['email'] = $args['email'];

$node = node_submit($node);
try {
  node_save($node);
  $node_id = $node->nid;
  $arrResp['nid'] = $node_id;
  return $arrResp;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $response = 'Hubo un error, no se creó la reserva';
  $arrResp['error'] = $response;
  watchdog('room_reservations','Error in node creation',(array)$e,WATCHDOG_ERROR);
  return $arrResp;
}
} else {
watchdog('room_reservations','Did not recieve args');
return services_error(t('No se subieron datos!'),406, t('No se entregaron datos!'));
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the Services module defaults to calling `user_access()`, so you need to make your own `access callback` function, which would accept those permission names, then you could just return the result of a call to `user_access()` with the incoming params.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21services%21docs%21services.services.api.php/function/hook_services_resources/7) your array keys are named incorrectly, they should be:

```
'access arguments' => array('create room reservations standard','bypass minimum advance booking'),
'access arguments append' => TRUE,
```

With no underscores.

Comment: Updated the service declaration but I still get an "access denied" message